# How to import some functions from a file but not fill up the file namespace with vars that have the same name but also allow for tree shaking

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write my imports in a way that is tree shakeable, but I have some functions with the same name as in some other files. Is there a way to import all of these functions into the same file without causing naming conflicts?

Below is a generic example:

```js
// Car.ts
export function doSomething () { /* doSomething logic */ }
export function doSomethingElse () { /* doSomethingElse logic */ }
export function doA3rdThing () { /* doA3rdThing logic */ }

// User.ts
export function doSomething () { /* doSomething logic */ }
export function doSomethingElse () { /* doSomethingElse logic */ }
export function doA3rdThing () { /* doA3rdThing logic */ }

// index.ts
import { doSomething, doSomethingElse, doA3rdThing } from './Car'
import { doSomething, doSomethingElse, doA3rdThing } from './User'

// error: Duplicate identifier 'doSomething'.
// error: Duplicate identifier 'doSomethingElse'.
// error: Duplicate identifier 'doA3rdThing'.
```

Something like this would be great:

```js
import { doSomething, doSomethingElse, doA3rdThing } as Car from './Car'
import { doSomething, doSomethingElse, doA3rdThing } as User from './User'

Car.doSomething() 
User.doSomething()

// no longer duplicate identifiers and could be tree shakeable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { doSomething as carDoSomething, doSomethingElse as carDoSomethingElse } from './Car'
import { doSomething as userDoSomething, doSomethingElse as userDoSomethingElse } from './User'
```

Comment: that could work except that I have a lot of functions like this so I would be writing tons of aliases which is a lot of work.